# Election primaries appear to perpetually check the candidate reputation

Tags: bug, status-completed, election

It's been 7 months since the [2011 Stack Overflow election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/1), and it's been a fun ride, hasn't it? A few of us were just reviewing the entries, when we noticed that [Tim Post](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50049), one of the elected moderators, is [not present in the primaries phase](https://stackoverflow.com/election/1?tab=primary).

Clearly, he was in the primaries since he got elected. But all 30 slots in the primaries are filled, and he's not there. Further digging shows that Tim's *current* reputation is insufficient to put him in the primaries when compared against the original pool of 56 nominees and their *current* reputation after 7 months. That is, **the primaries phase of a completed election appears to filter based on the current reputation of nominees rather than who actually made it to the primaries**.

Not many sites get affected by this, but it remains something to be investigated.

Comment: It's like studying _Modern History_

Comment: Another demonstration that becoming a moderator is detrimental to your rep.

Comment: It's not a bug. I'm just a Ninja :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We will show all candidates regardless of reputation for both the nomination / primary phases of a historical election.

Comment: Did those elections really require 30,000 reputation??