# Election page is not showing all candidates for the Jan/Feb 2011 election

Tags: bug, user-interface, election

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Election primaries appear to perpetually check the candidate reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102260/election-primaries-appear-to-perpetually-check-the-candidate-reputation)

I just went back to the [page for the first 2011 election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/1?tab=primary) to gather some data and found that some candidates are not being displayed. I originally noticed this because Tim Post, who was one of the winners, wasn't showing up.

On further inspection, I realized that only 30 candidates are showing up per page. Since there were 56 candidates in all, almost half of them are being hidden. Perhaps this is due to the current (Nov 2011) election rules being used for display?