# Bad informations on 2011 elections page?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, wording, election-page

On 2011 SO election page there is written  that minimal reputation to nominate themself is 32645 - but I saw that elected moderator Tim Post has only 19687 reputation points ! Is possible to lose about 13000 reps - I think that not. So how could he nominate himself if he hadn't got required reputation points ?

Screenshot (also avaliable [here](https://stackoverflow.com/election/1)) :

> [image]

Comment: That's obviously a bug/typo.

Comment: _Could_ be related to localization, checking on this

Comment: @Tim nope, it's a very old bug - see [snapshot of the page from January 18th, 2012](http://web.archive.org/web/20120118205127/http://stackoverflow.com/election/1) - it says 20,316 points there. The number is somehow *dynamic*. Amazing how nobody saw this until now!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - There was a similar bug reported earlier: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102260/election-primaries-appear-to-perpetually-check-the-candidate-reputation , where Tim had been removed from the list due to this.

Comment: @Brad so you say it's for real, i.e. back then users had to have this insane rep and it was only later changed to 3000? (300 on other sites)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - By default, the minimum bar for reputation required to nominate yourself was based the reputations of the top 30 people who had already nominated themselves. At the time, Tim cleared that easily (it was below 10k), but reputations of the others increased at a pace greater than his, and the page didn't snapshot the reputation scores of everyone involved at that moment. The addition of moderator-related badges as a nomination requirement has made reputation score less of a factor in these nominations since.

Comment: @Brad wow that sounds ubber-complicated... really glad it was changed. Feel free to mark this [meta-tag:status-bydesign] then! (and of course explain what you told me in a full answer :-))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Brad said [in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198874/bad-informations-on-2011-elections-page#comment630961_198874):

> the minimum bar for reputation required to nominate yourself was based the reputations of the top 30 people who had already nominated themselves

This apply only for the very first elections, afterwards it was changed to fixed 3,000 on Stack Overflow and 300 on other sites.

So the reputation requirement for the 2011 Moderator Election is indeed dynamic and ever increasing - by design.